# Securing API Key in Angular2

Tags: node.js, security, express, angular, json-web-token

I've been googling more than a day now. May be I'm missing the correct keywords.

I have the following setup:

- ExpressJS API (running with pm2 on port 3000)
- Angular2 app - served
  via nginx

Both run on the same server.

Calls to the api (mydomain/api/) are proxied to `127.0.0.1:3000`

For api calls which require authorization I will use JWT and user authentication.

What I want to achieve is that I generate a token for my angular2 app which is allowed/required to make the public calls (listings of products for example).

This token needs to be transferred securely of course as I don't want others obtain my products and prices via direct api calls (with a stolen token).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, as @eesdil said, you must use HTTPS. In that case, all your calls are encrypted and safe.

In my example ( Angular 2, Express and JWT ), i used crypto module with pbkdf2 algorithm for hashing passwords.

This is workflow:

- /login/signup -> hash password and generate salt -> store it on server
- /login -> validate password against stored one -> generate jwt -> save it in localStorage on client
- /api -> send jwt in **Auth** header -> validate on server -> send response

Working example is here: https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. But let's say your starter app would list cities at the homepage. I don't want people to call api/cities directly. So I generated a JWT which is internally assigned to the public api calls. I could provide the Public JWT via express-session in a secure way I guess. I'll setup https and my idea in the whole thing and come back with the result.

Comment: No, don't use session and cookies for storing or transferring jwt token. No matter from what location they call /api/cities they need to have valid jwt.  I will improve my example with /refresh functionality. You can encode jwt on client side and see when they expiring...

Answer (score 0):

Your token hopefully travels with https. And when it does they cannot get it...

UPDATE

from wiki:

> Because HTTPS piggybacks HTTP entirely on top of TLS, the entirety of
>   the underlying HTTP protocol can be encrypted. This includes the
>   request URL (which particular web page was requested), query
>   parameters, headers,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS

Comment: Sorry I'm a little stupid in this section. I will setup https of course. But i will still have to include my public token in a Request Header/url param from the angular app, so it's visible to anyone. Or am I missing something?

Comment: see the wiki, as https is application layer protocol it is encrypting also the headers.

Comment: Yes, you mast include token in each call. But that token is generated on server... I have similar setup right now ( express - angular 2 ) i will submit my workflow as answer here.

Comment: That would be awesome @VladoTesanovic